# Best way to implement uploading to separate fileserver?

Tags: node.js, express, iis, multer, iisnode

So we've got a webpage made with node.js, express and mongodb.
I've got 2 servers in DMZ, not joined to AD.
One of the servers will be serving the webpage, while the other will purely receive and serve videofiles.
The servers are running iis and iisnode.

Currently the page is using multer for uploading files, which works fine for uploading to the same server the code is running on.
Uploading to a separate server is proving to be harder though, and my googling isnt getting me any closer to the solution.
I want the uploads and downloads to go directly between the client and the videoserver, not through the webserver.

Any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: Can't you just create this api on the video server ? It will save your bandwidth for transferring the uploaded file from one server to another.

Comment: Yeah, I want to avoid having to send the files between servers. I'm not sure how to though. So far I'm not finding anything that suggests that there is built in support for uploading to a different server than the one running the webpage. I've been considering figuring out how to set the videoserver up to receive http post requests, but i'm unsure how easy it is to set up in node.js/express. Part of the problem here is the dev of the page has been away on sickleave for over a month, and I'm trying to set up the servers in his absence.

Comment: Simple express server setup http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html    You just now need to transfer the upload logic from your webpage server to video server.

Comment: How does one call the upload logic from the webpage then? It's looking like i'm gonna have to do the rewrite of the webpage as well, but I really don't know node.js

Comment: Ya you can either copy the code from webpage server or try implementing it using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: How do I call the "upload-app" from the "webpage-app"? Uploading is supposed to be seemlessly integrated on the webpage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157870/discussion-between-amanpurohit-and-ceero).

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction here?`